# React-Native : change state when app is in background

Tags: react-native

I create a simple app that using React Native `AppState`:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text , View} from 'react-native'


export default  class AppStateExample extends  React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name:'not change'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {

    if(AppState.currentState=='background'){
      console.log('background mode');
      this.setState({name:'back'});
    }
    if(AppState.currentState =='active'){
      //...
    }
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>State Name : {this.state.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

And when I try switch app from foreground to background and then background to foreground `console.log('background mode');` work very well and console
print `'background mode'`

**BUT**

The `this.setState({name:'back'});` not working and I see `'not change'` text in view

Comment: Do you find any reason why the `this.setState` doesn't work? for my case, the `setState` does not exist at all and it is very weird.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, based on [React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) on `AppState` change for Functional Component I prefer to write code like below:

```js
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppState } from "react-native";

const AppStateManager = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener("change", handleAppStateChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
    }

    appState.current = nextAppState;
    setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    console.log("AppState", appState.current);
  };

  return null;
};

export default AppStateManager;
```

Surely, we can use this component in the root of the project just like a React Component:

```js
~~~
  <App>
    ~~
    <AppStateManager />
    ~~
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, `AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);` is too late to register.
You probably want to listen AppState the first thing in your app before main components get loaded and pass down the values probably by your state management library

Comment: I listen to AppState in componentDidMount method like react native document for AppState , how can I sure to AppState listener is register ?

Comment: May be Add it in your App.js . What are you using for state management ?

Comment: I use react-native state like  this.setState()  or this.state and not use state managment like redux

Comment: I upload simple project without (node_modules , android , ios) folder https://files.fm/u/fvsd8pxk#_

Comment: Ok. So that is because when you are seeing the UI, you are no more in background mode. You can only see it in console.log or something like that.

Comment: I also try test with set time out or set interval that print with console.log when app is in background mode  after 1 second but this  not working and console just  print  'background mode' and  not print any text in console after 1 second

Comment: It is expected to print background mode because you are background mode. and after  a while it goes into suspended state (ie. in iOS). You cannot expect a timer to keep running. What exactly are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want give and proccess gps data  and then store in asyncstorage or post it  to the rest api when app is in background

Comment: Oh. That is a huge one. You need to checkout Background execution https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1  for iOS. There are some existing native modules that do that. https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location

Comment: thanks a lot for response , cant  I  do this just with AppState?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171546/discussion-between-agent-hunt-and-roox).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a switch that wrap all endPoint
note: to get appState status AppState.currentState

```js
this.state = {
  appState: AppState.currentState
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html
};


componentWillMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', () => this._handleAppStateChange());
};


componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', () => this._handleAppStateChange());
}

_handleAppStateChange() {
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html
  const {
    appState
  } = this.state;
  console.warn({
    appState
  })

  this.fetchData().catch(error => error);

  switch (appState) {
    case 'active': //The app is running in the foreground
      this.onStart();
      break;
    case 'background': // The app is running in the background. The user is either
      this.onEnd();
      console.warn('background');
      break;

    case 'inactive':
      // The app transitioning between foreground & background or entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call
      console.warn('Inactive');
      break;

    default:
      console.warn('_handleAppStateChange default');
  }
}
```